# Is it possible to test this Kotlin class?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, abstract-class, protected

I am trying to write unit test cases for a Kotlin class A and trying to mock return client() call present in test() method to unit test test() method:

```
A.kt kotlin class:
class A (par 1, par 2) : B(par 1, par 2) {
   override fun test(item: String): Boolean {
      return client()
   }
}


B.kt kotlin class:
abstract class B(par 1, par 2) {
    private val client: WebClient by lazy {
        //does something
    }
    protected fun client(): WebClient = client
}
```

Is it possible to mock the client() call in test() method? 
And if possible how to do it and what library should I use for mocking?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) testing framework. However, mocking an object returned from a object's method would require mocking the object itself.

```
val mockOfA = Mockito.mock(A::class)
val mockOfClient = Mockito.mock(WebClient:class)
Mockito.when(mockOfA.test(anyString())).thenReturn(mockOfClient)  // Mind your original snippet return type Boolean from A.test()
```

If your class `A` implements internal logic you want to test in your test scenario, there are two possible paths:

- Create a [Spy](https://javapointers.com/tutorial/difference-between-spy-and-mock-in-mockito/) instead of a Mock. Mocks do only whatever you explicitly set them up to do. Spy 'falls back' to original implementation when it is not given any mock behaviour.
- Rewrite you class `A` so that it depends on external dependency of a `ClientProvider` to get an instance of `WebClient` to return in method `test()` and inject a mock of said provider to your object of type `A` during the test.

Comment: client().post().uri("some uri").syncBody(body).execute(uri, exception) - this is the complete so it returns a boolean